# How to find the translate point for layout in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, zooming

In android, I have scaled the layout using ScaleGesture and applying those Scale to ScaleX and ScaleY property of layout. In every pointer up action , I am rendering the layout based on the current scale value. For I have calculated the translate point like below,

```
    var xCoord = currentZoomPoint.X / controlWidth;
var yCoord = currentZoomPoint.Y / controlHeight;
layout.TranslatePoint.X += (float)((width* (previousScale- currentScale)) *xCoord ) ; 
layout.TranslatePoint.Y += (float)((height * (previousScale - currentScale))* yCoord) ;
```

But the current zoom position changing widely, when difference between current zoom level and the previous zoom level is high.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want zoom and pan a layout. I have achievied zooming using matrix and panning using the gesture listener. But when using gesture listener the TranslateX and TranslateY set for the layout is not updated in the matrix

Comment: u wanna zoom and pan the layout same time?